# Find the intersection line between two colors

Tags: python, image, colors

I'm trying to find the intersection between color green and blue of a set of images that are similar to this one:

[image]

So what I need is something is something like this:

[image]

And because I need to use the contours for some calculus after that I would like to know if it's possible to have the points of the curve in an array or something... but I have no idea if this is possible. I tried to do the mask but I don't think it's going to work... here's the code:

```
        lower_val = np.array([0, 0, 0])

        upper_val = np.array([150, 255, 150])

        mask = cv2.inRange(image, lower_val, upper_val)
        only_lumen = cv2.bitwise_and(image, image, mask=mask)
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(only_lumen, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (3, 3), 0)
        thresh = cv2.threshold(blur, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
        thresh = 255 - thresh
```

This is how I'm trying to display the points:

```
    x, y = [i[0] for i in pts_list], [i[1] for i in pts_list]
    max_x, max_y = max(x), max(y)

    image = np.zeros((max_y + 1, max_x + 1))

    for i in range(len(pts_list)):
        image[max_y - y[i], x[i]] = 1
```

And this is the image I obtain:
[image]

I don't understand why the dots meet in a corner and why the background is violet... The lines where supposed to be in the middel

Comment: These are the things which I think you need to specify better to make your question more specific: 1) Can we assume that background will be black always? 2) do you want the intersection points only between the two foreground colors (here it's blue and green) and not with the background ? 3) Will the foreground colors be just 2 ? 4) Will it be just the ones you have mentioned or will it vary ? 5) Here there are two sets of intersections, like that if there are many such intersections do you want them as separately grouped list of points or as a single list of points?

Comment: There more information you provide by editing your post the better the answer will be. But yes, with the given information it is possible to extract the set of points. I will write the answer making my own assumptions(based on the current info you have provided) for the question.

Comment: Hi!! Thank you so much or your answer:) I'm going to answer your points, again, thank you so much!! 1) yes, it's always going to be black. 2) My idea it's only between foreground colors (in this case blue and green). 3) Yes, they are only two  4) They can vary, so my idea was to make them as a parameter. 5)  I didin't think about it before but maybe in two lists is better? What I want to do after that it's to calculate the vectors of direction to see if the surface it's regular or not. So my idea was comparing each vector with the previous one to see if the direction it's similiar (regular)

Comment: or very different (would be irregular). Thank you!!!

Comment: Thank you for providing more information. It would be great if you can add these information to your question by editing it, so that others who are viewing the post may be able to help  you out better. Give me some time while I code and test the result.

Comment: I have shared a simple answer, I have something else to do now. When am done with that I will post a much better solution after testing it like this again. Let me know if this what you need.

Answer (score 2):

For now, I will give you the simplest of solutions you can try (can be improved a lot):

Boundary pixels (after getting the masks) will be adjacent to each other but you have to pick a side if you want 1 pixel width boundary as minimum. Alternative to this is to set search kernel and use morphology to dilate your color masks according to your search kernel. The common points in the dilated masks will be the neighborhood points which you can extract by simply doing a Bitwise AND.

```
# Define the color ranges for each color of interest for creating masks.
COLOR1_RANGE = [(30, 0, 0), (255, 50, 50)]  # Blue in BGR, [(low), (high)].
COLOR2_RANGE = [(0, 30, 0), (50, 255, 50)]  # Green in BGR, [(low), (high)].

# Create masks:
color1_mask = cv2.inRange(self.img, COLOR1_RANGE[0], COLOR1_RANGE[1])
color2_mask = cv2.inRange(self.img, COLOR2_RANGE[0], COLOR2_RANGE[1])

# Adjust according to your adjacency requirement.
kernel = np.ones((3, 3), dtype=np.uint8)

# Dilating masks to expand boundary.
color1_mask = cv2.dilate(color1_mask, kernel, iterations=1)
color2_mask = cv2.dilate(color2_mask, kernel, iterations=1)

# Required points now will have both color's mask val as 255.
common = cv2.bitwise_and(color1_mask, color2_mask)

# Common is binary np.uint8 image, min = 0, max = 255.
# SOME_THRESHOLD can be anything within the above range. (not needed though)
# Extract/Use it in whatever way you want it.
intersection_points = np.where(common > SOME_THRESHOLD)

# Say you want these points in a list form, then you can do this.
pts_list = [[r, c] for r, c in zip(*intersection_points)]
print(pts_list)
```

**Some Sample Outputs:**

Input 01 (Simple):
[image: Simple Input]

Output 01 (Simple):
[image: Simple Output]

Output Points as List (Partial):

```
pts_list = [[99, 104], [99, 105], [100, 104], [100, 105], [100, 106], ...]
```

Input 02 (Complex):
[image: Complex Input]

Output 02 (Complex):
[image: Complex Output]

Output Points as List (Partial):

```
pts_list = [[127, 309], [127, 310], [127, 311], [127, 312], [127, 313], ...]
```

Update 1:
I made a small change in the code comments to make it more understandable.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! That's exactly what I needed:) but I have a problem displaying the points, I edited the question to attach an image. Thanks again

Comment: So if you want to reuse those points in Computer Vision domain (like with OpenCV, PIL, matplotlib etc..) I recommend to use the intersection_points variable. The pts_list is a conversion to make it print it in a human readable form (less efficient to use it for computations again, but might be useful for debugging)

Comment: I am assuming you are passing a gray scale image to a matplotlib.pyplot  imshow() without changing its cmap.

Comment: Do provide me the details about how you are trying to display the image. Regarding the points being in the corner you are using row points as x (rows are supposed to be y) and vice versa.

Comment: It's a common mistake lot of people will make. As intuitively we represent coordinates in (x, y) but images etc are mostly considered like matrices which are represented in (row, col) but these in coordinate sense are actually (y, x).

Comment: Do reach me out if you need more clarification. I will gladly help you out.